# How can I split the Apache camel AWS-S3 messages

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-camel

I have an requirement to move the files from one S3 bucket to another S3 bucket, during this process I need to split the file (that is an image file).

So, this is how I am doing

```
camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {

            from(sourcePoint.getS3SourcePoint()).split().method(new SheetImageSplitterImpl(), "split").to(destinationPoint.getS3DestinationPoint());
        }
    });

    camelContext.start();
```

Inside `SheetImageSplitter's split()` method, I am trying to implement the logic to split the image file. The exchange body returns me a body of type S3Object.inputStream. I do not find any help to convert the S3ObjectInputStream to image files

```
public List<Message> split(Exchange exchange) {

    System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody());
}
```

Is there way, So that I can process the image files

Note : I am using Java DSL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert that `S3ObjectInputStream` as `InputStream` and put it back into the message

```
public List<message> split(Exchange exchange){
      InputStream iStream = (InputStream) exchange.getIn().getBody();
      File file = new File("tmp/filename.jpg");
      FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(iStream, file);

      List<File> files = <your splitting logic method>

      List<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<Message>();
      for (File file : files) {
           DefaultMessage message = new DefaultMessage(); 
           InputStream ip = new FileInputStream(file.getName());
           message.setBody((InputStream) ip);
           messageList.add(message);
    }
    return messageList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to split an image file? I don't know S3, but following code should create an image file:

```
BufferedImage imBuff = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
```

Hope, it helps.